# Interpreting K-Means cluster_centers_ output

Tags: python-3.x, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I am having difficulty interpreting the results of the `cluster_centers_` array output.

Consider the following MWE:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np

# Load the data
iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

# shuffle the data
shuffle = np.random.permutation(np.arange(X.shape[0]))
X = X[shuffle]

# scale X
X = (X - X.mean()) / X.std()

# plot K-means centroids
km = KMeans(n_clusters = 2, n_init = 10)  # establish the model

# fit the data
km.fit(X);

# km centers
km.cluster_centers_
```

```
array([[ 1.43706001, -0.29278015,  0.75703227, -0.89603057],
       [ 0.78079175, -0.04797174, -0.96467783, -1.60799713]])
```

In the array above, it is unclear to me how I use these values to identify the cluster center. I told K-Means to give me 2 clusters, yet it returns 8 values for me, but they cannot be x, y coordinates for all 4 features.

If I plot `1.43706001, -0.29278015`; this makes intuitive sense, its a cluster right in the middle of a predicted cluster.

[image: Example Cluster Location]

So if this is the case, and my second cluster is `0.78079175, -0.04797174`, what are the values in columns 2 and 3 for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From documentation 
`cluster_centers_`: ndarray of shape (n_clusters, n_features)

The iris database has 4 features (`X.shape = (150,4)`), you want Kmeans to get two centroids in 4-dimensional feature space. `cluster_centers_` does exactly that, each entry of list corresponds to the coordinates of the centroid in R^4.

Comment: in the cluster_centers_ array, does the first entry in the array correspond to label 0, the seconds entry to label 2,like this

Comment: Kinda. First entry - label 1, second entry - label 2 (you just mixed 0-indexed and 1-indexed)